# Flickr API - Ruby on Rails App (Not running)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, flickr

I'm following this tutorial to do a Ruby on Rails app that pulls photos from Flickr when you do a search, it seems really simple but when I do "rails server" to see the results I get this on the terminal:

```
rails server

rails server
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:275:in `check_part': Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:255:in `check_controller_and_action'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:178:in `normalize_options!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:100:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `build'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1560:in `add_route'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1537:in `decomposed_match'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1518:in `block in match'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1508:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1508:in `match'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:690:in `map_method'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:659:in `post'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/javiersanchezsanchez/Documents/Ruby/Tests/flickr/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

**Can anyone help me?**

Comment: It looks like there's a problem in your `config/routes.rb` file. Can you post what you have in there?

Comment: `Flickr::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'flickr#index'
  post :search => 'flickr#search'
end
`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your routing error is coming from your second route, which should be a string instead of a symbol. Try the following in your router:

```
Flickr::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'flickr#index'
  post 'search' => 'flickr#search'
end
```

As a syntax shortcut, you can also use `to:` instead of `:to =>` on your first route; both will use a symbol as the key.